# Best Design Practices for Passing Around Multithread Data?

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to create a clean and efficient design for passing off events to a background thread for evaluation, then return a selected result to the game thread.

This is my initial design

```
//Occurrence object passed from director on game thread to background thread OccurrenceQueue

    //Execute BackgroundThread::EvaluateQueues()

        //If OccurrenceQueue.Dequeue()

            //Score Occurrence, then return via Occurrence.GetOwner()->PurposeSelected(Occurrence)

            //EvaluateQueues()
```

This resulted in a clean loop of selecting a chain of purposes from an event. So now I want to move this to a background thread. Here is what I've learned so far:

- Thread Safety (in UE) requires absolutely no modification of UObject
  data from other threads (From what I read this is due to their custom
  GC)

  - You can lock objects and/or design so that objects in background
    thread aren't touched by game thread, but there is still a risk of
    unexpected behavior due to lifetime not being extended by background
    thread and synchonization issues
- You cannot simply execute a function on a game thread existing object
  to move the callstack back to game thread

  - Calling Occurrence.GetOwner()->PurposeSelected(Occurrence) from a
    background thread remains in the background thread

    - This is the main subject I'd like to get a better understanding of
  - This applies to delegates in UE as well
- TQueues in UE can be used across threads safely

From what I've learned above, my current design doesn't appear to be logically possible.

These are my alternatives thus far:

- Use two queues

  - One to dequeue and score on the background thread
  - The other to dequeue the result on game thread via tick
- Use a delegate existing on the game thread, which calls OccurrenceEvaluated.Broadcast() through tick

  - When a result is scored, bind Occurrence.GetOwner()->PurposeSelected(Occurrence) to OccurrenceEvaluated
- I've seen that c++ utilizes something called Future() (or something like that) for ASync tasks, and it appears UE has something similar with  TFuture<> && TFuture.IsReady(), but I have yet to look deeper into that and how it returns data

  - Same with FAsyncTask

I'm hesitant to implement any design which utilizes tick to check if data has been updated/returned from background threads.

Can anyone suggest relevant design practices, or clarify the nature of returning execution to a main thread from a background thread (I've had a hard time finding the right question to research/info regarding this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a perfect solution. As these events aren't particularly time sensitive, I just use Unreal Engine's AsyncTask() to schedule an async task on the game thread from my background thread. As @Pepjin Kramer pointed out is the same as std::async.

So simple it's basically a slap in the face.

Answer (score -1):

Goodmorning,

Threading can help you get things done faster/more responsive but has a lot of pitfalls. The short answer in situations like this I use these kind of constructs

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector> 

int main()
{
     // make data shared
     auto data = std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>();
     data -> push_back(42);

     // future will be a future<int> deduced from return from vector
     // async will run lambda in other thread
     // capture data by value! It copies the shared_ptr and will
     // increase its reference count.
     auto future = std::async(std::launch::async, [data]
     {
        auto value = data[0];
        return value;
        // shared_ptr data goes out of scope and reference count to data is decreased
     });

     // synchronize with thread and get "calculated" value
     auto my_value = future.get();
    // now data on the main thread goes out of scope reference count is decreased. Only when both the thread are done AND this function exits then data is deleted.
    return 0;
}
```

- Most objects take up memory and during assignments that memory isn't updated in 1 clock cycle. You can protect memory with sdt::mutex and std::scoped_lock. Try looking for those.
- You often need to synchronize information/processing between threads, look at std::condition_variable (but they have pitfalls https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables)
- C++ has good support classes, std::thread and std::async/std::future. Personally I like the solution with std::future because you can return values and exceptions
  (!) from other threads when you call future.get()
- Learn about lambdas and captures, they're vital for use with std::thread/std::async
- Life cycle of objects! When sharing objects between threads you must be sure that one thread doesn't delete objects in use by other threads. Don't use raw pointers and/or new/delete when using threads. I personally often use std::make_shared/std::shared_ptr's to data/objects when sharing information between threads.
- Another tricky thing is that sometimes you cannot be sure work in another thread has started after creating it. E.g. When std::async returns a thread is created but it isn't guaranteed to have really started (operating system scheduling etc...) . If you want to be really sure it has started then after the async call returns you will have to wait on a condition_variable you set at the start of the thread function.

I hope these remarks can get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I can say I understand most of the points you mentioned (life cycle, using objects in a thread safe manner, etc.)

 It seems Unreal Engine's version of future.get() will likely be the closest solution to what I want. I'm beginning to research it today.

 I'm not sure quite how to phrase it, but mainly I'm trying to understand how to move a callstack from one thread to another. Like if I were to call Run() on a background thread from the game thread, it executes on the game thread, and vice versa. If I can understand that I can design around that understanding.

Comment: You can't really move callstacks between threads. The closest thing is probable making a lambda with (copy) captured variables (which you can kind of see like a copy of the stack).

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Core/Async/Async/ seems close to std::async, it just has this extra callback that's called upon completion.  So it might be a good start though I never used unreal ;)

Comment: I didn't think so, I was hoping maybe there was a design trick to work around that, in order to pass back data. I was just looking at the source code for FRunnableThread (which is the background thread I was using to process a queue) to see if I could figure out how they create an object on game thread but run on a background thread, but it's a bit beyond my understanding. Hopefully FAsyncTask pans out, I'll make sure to add a solution if I find one. Thanks!

Comment: The solution is so going to depend on what you want to do with the background thread. 
I can imagine the game thread being an observer, just checking every now and then if the background has new data ready. Or the background just calculates new values, updates them in memory that's accessible to both thread and the game thread only reads them when it is ready (data protected by mutexes ofcourse). Good luck finding a solution!

Comment: Yeah, I did create a working solution doing exactly that, where once the background thread processed the event, it bound it to a delegate existing on the game thread. I could either allow the delegate to be broadcast every tick or manually tell the game thread when to tick, but I really don't like the design of it. It works, it's just not clean to me. I'm self taught, so there are a lot of design paradigms I'm unaware of, and in my lack of traditional learning it strikes me as unprofessional. I'm trying to avoid tick, and thus far I have

Comment: Well, I found a solution that makes me look stupid it's so simple haha. All I have to do is use UE's version of std::Async like you said, and I can pass my data object from the background thread to the main thread exactly like I'd hoped. Thanks for taking the time to give me advice!

Comment: Jay! Succes! Happy coding :)